# Cassandra error for JAVA

Tags: java, cassandra

I am facing this problem. I have started the cassandra properly, but I don't understand the error why I am facing this.

```
aims@aims:~$ sudo service cassandra start
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
aims@aims:~$ sudo service cassandra status
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-11-24 19:12:59 PST; 15min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 14796 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cassandra stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16659 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 24 19:12:59 aims systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed storage system for structured data...
Nov 24 19:12:59 aims systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
Nov 24 19:28:19 aims systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
aims@aims:~$ cd cassandra/
aims@aims:~/cassandra$ bin/cassandra 
aims@aims:~/cassandra$ OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file bin/../logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
```

Kindly let me know why I am facing this sort of issue.

This is where my JAVA resides:

```
aims@aims:~/cassandra$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/aims/java/bin
```

Hope to hear a solution for me.

Comment: the `JAVA_HOME` should rather be `/home/aims/java`

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=/home/aims/java`, then try again

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thank you.. let me check it.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto After trying what you have mentioned I got this error: `Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.`

Comment: I guess it is clear enough, you need to upgrade your version of java

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Yes I know I have updated my JAVA too. But still I get the same error. Please let me know if I am wrong somewhere. See this I have used this link for updating JAVA- http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/#

Comment: have you set CASSANDRA_HOME ?

Comment: what does `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` return ?

Comment: @root545 Yes I did

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I have already mentioned it

Comment: hwo did you install cassandra ?

Comment: @root545 Well I think I have already mentioned that too in the previous comments. I have visited the link http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/# and have installed the java

Comment: I asked how u installed cassandra not java ?

Comment: oops.. sorry .. Well, I have the instructions available on the Cassandra website. http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ Just follow the steps of debian installation.

Answer (score 0):

inside your $CASSANDRA_HOME make logs directory.

```
su root
enter password
bin/cassandra -f -R
```

Answer (score 0):

ERROR due to your java_home path not set properly.I did below changes on .bashrc file on linux.Then I try to start cassandra process.It started normal.

```
cassandra@aiops-dev-cassandra1:~$ date
Mon Dec  9 12:59:40 UTC 2019
cassandra@aiops-dev-cassandra1:~/apache-cassandra-3.11.0/bin$ ./cassandra -R
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
cassandra@aiops-dev-cassandra1:~/apache-cassandra-3.11.0/bin$

cassandra@aiops-dev-cassandra1:~$ more .bashrc
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
#PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64
#export JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
#export CASSANDRA_HOME=/home/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.0
#export CASSANDRA_CONF=$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf
#export DSE_HOME=/opt/dse/dse-4.6.11
#export TMP=/tmp
#export TMPDIR=$TMP
#export log=/home/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.0/logs
#export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin:.
#export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext:$CASSANDRA_HOME/lib:.
#alias casslog='tail -100f $CASSANDRA_LOG'
#export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '

#export PATH

cassandra@aiops-dev-cassandra1:~$

[cassandra@aiops-dev-cassandra1 bin]$ ./cassandra -R
[cassandra@aiops-dev-cassandra1 bin]$ CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset (Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
```